# How to install to the Public directory in Windows 7 from the VS 2010 deployment Setup Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have some documents I want to install (using the Setup project) onto a Windows 7 system which is accessible by everyone. These documents should not be hidden. They should be visible for all users to double click on. I believe the best place for this is C:\Users\Public or C:\Users\Public\Documents.

Since there isn't a special folder for either of these folders in the Setup project, the only way I have found so far is to create a custom folder and set the DefaultLocation to [%public][Manufacturer][ProductName] etc.

(see http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-164246.html)

However, this seems very brittle; what if someone deletes the environment variable for public? Also, would this work on a different language version of Windows 7? Is there a better way to define the DefaultLocation to the Public folder for a Windows 7 install?

Comment: Public didn't become available until Vista.  SHGetKnownFolderPath to retrieve it.  If you need to support XP then do consider just creating your own folder.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/downloads-folder-not-special-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public folder isn't stored in a standard environment variable (System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables) so I think it is very unlikely too many people are doing this, but I understand the need to create a robust installer.

This [page](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/924138a5-bdb2-4ab4-870b-57b3a8b8ff44) has instructions on changing the location of the public folder. The accepted solution is quite involved and requires command line work. The suggestion by Luviana is much simpler. I would test them out and see if they break the %public% shortcut. My guess is that they will not. My best advice is to check it out for yourself and if it still works then you can count on the fact that %public% will be available.

Comment: To fully answer your question - the environment variables will be the same across languages. So %public% will work. However, if you were after a subfolder then that could be different. For example %public%/music may have the music folder in a different language. I cannot think of a more robust means of specifying public than the system variable %public%

Comment: Thanks mrtsherman, I imagine this also applies when programmatically referencing the public folder, e.g.: Directory = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("public") + "MyCompanyName" etc. ?