# Obtaining path of users directory

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

How to get path of Users folder from windows service on MS Vista?
I think about path  of **C:\Users** directory, but it may be different location depend on system localization.

Comment: Do you want the particular home path for a particular user?  There's no guarantee that all users would have their home folders in the same location.  (Remote home folders, for instance.)

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), e.g.

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
```

Adjust for the special folder you want.  However, in reading another post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649810/how-to-reference-the-c-users-public-directory-programmatically-in-c-sharp), it looks like you may need to do a little manipulation of the string if you want exactly *c:\users* instead of *c:\users\public*, for example.

Answer (score 7):

System.Environment.SpecialFolder will give you access to all these folders that you want, such as My Documents, Etc..

If you use the UserProfile SpecialFolder, that should give you the path to your profile under Users.

```
string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way as @Neil pointed out is to use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [`FOLDERID_UserProfiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx#folderid_userprofiles). However, c# doesn't have that. But, it's not that hard to invoke it:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SOExample
{
    public class Main
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);

        private static string getUserProfilesPath()
        {
            // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx#folderid_userprofiles
            Guid UserProfilesGuid = new Guid("0762D272-C50A-4BB0-A382-697DCD729B80");
            IntPtr pPath;
            SHGetKnownFolderPath(UserProfilesGuid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pPath);

            string path = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pPath);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pPath);
            return path;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = getUserProfilesPath(); // C:\Users
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see that function exposed to .NET, but in C(++) it would be

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_UserProfiles, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this iv via:

```
var usersFolder = Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
```

Now I am not a Windows specialist, but I think that always goes to the root folder where all profiles are stored, if a user has a roaming profile on some server that he's loaded via the network drive then you're out of luck I guess unless you're on the domain controller and you query the profile for the roaming path.