# Where is the best path to store desktop applications data on each OS?

Tags: desktop-application

I want to make a cross-platform desktop app which has a small config file on local filesystem.
Where is the best path to store application data on each OS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377977/where-to-store-user-data-for-a-desktop-application for windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510104/where-to-store-application-data-non-user-specific-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually games or apps whose data is to be stored,and not deleted even after uninstalling the app itself,is stored in the users own path:

C:/Users/username/appdata

The appdata directory is hidden so you can either go there from cmd,or unhide it from:

folder options(search in windows tab)/view

Hope this was useful.