# Get SpecialFolder.MyDocuments folders of each user

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have a windows service running on my machine. How can I get MyDocuments folders of each users?

For example:

For Windows XP I must get list:

- C:\Documents and Settings\User1\My Documents
- C:\Documents and Settings\User2\My Documents
- ...

For Windows 10 I must get list:

- C:\Users\User1\Documents\
- C:\Users\User2\Documents\
- ...

How can I get these lists ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752173/3179310) and then just enumerate folders ( for each user ).

```
// getUserProfilesPath() is a method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752173/3179310
string path = getUserProfilesPath();
// now use WMIC to get all users on the local machine
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject result in searcher.Get())
{
    // and check if their folder exists
    if(Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path, result["Name"])))
    {
        // user folder exists so now check if it has Documents folder
        if(DirectoryExists(Path.Combine(path, result["Name"], "Documents")))
        {
            DirectoryInfo userDocuments = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(path, result["Name"], "Documents"));
            // userDocuments is now a directory info of that user's documents folder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, you cannot hardcode the "Documents" string. It is also possible to move these special folders outside the profile directory.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, you're right. I will edit this answer later on to get the actual name of the documents folder.

Comment: The documents folder can have per-user custom names, there is no true generic name.

Comment: As you said **CAN HAVE**. On fresh machine they will all be in %userpofile% directory with the name "documents" or "mydocuments". Question did not specified behavior that you're describing.

Comment: I moved folder from C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ to D:\Abracadabra, but I can't get "D:\Abracadabra" from Windows Service :-(

Comment: So why did you move it then? If you want to track all of these things it's almost impossible to get the correct path.

Comment: User moved his Documents folder (I don't know why). And Windows Service should detect this. So it's impossible. Thanks for the answeres

Comment: It is still possible but I doubt that somebody will give you solution like that, you have more chances to get a solid answer if you show some effort on that topic.