# Get a list of all instances of a special folder (one per per user)

Tags: vb.net

I have a need to get the path to the Documents folder, but I need a list of paths, one for each user on the computer, not just the currently signed on User.  I don't need the one common Documents folder that is shared by everyone.  I need a list of all the user-specific ones.

I have successfully done this for the signed-on user with `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`, `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, and `SHGetFolderPath` without issue.

But is it possible to do this for all User accounts without using impersonation?

Comment: Do you want the common shared path or are you looking to get each user's individual folder?  If you need the documents folder that all users share, you can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)`

Comment: Hi...I'm looking to get the specifoc Documents folder for each user account on the computer. Not the "AllUsers" path. So say you have 5 users, each with different paths to Documents folder...I need that path for each User account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SpecialFolder.MyDocuments folders of each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945434/get-specialfolder-mydocuments-folders-of-each-user)

Comment: Thanks but that solution does not really work as each user documents folder could be different.

Comment: The registry hive of a User that is not logged in is unmounted. You could get it anyway, using [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), acquiring each User's access token. But, is it worth the effort?

Comment: Thanks...that was the route that I was going but I'm unsure how to get each user's access token without using impersonation. Is it even possible?

Comment: [GetKernelObjectSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-getkernelobjectsecurity). To get the Token handle (and testing the process right to get it): [OpenProcessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken). I think you'll decide that you don't really need to know the non-current user informations.