# Is there such thing as a same file directory for everyone in Windows10

Tags: c#

So I have been making an application where I edit a `.txt` file that I would like to send to other people, but it has my directory in it. It is basically `C:\users\(MYNAME)\etc...` and the application wouldn't work for anyone except me. Anyone have a solution on that.

My code is:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ME\XXX\XXX\XXX\options.txt");
text = text.Replace("text", "text");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ME\XXX\XXX\.XXX\options.txt", text);
```

Comment: So don't use the `Users` directory? As you can probably tell by name, each user will have their own. Somewhere else in C:\ is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes, so what would I need to use instead of 'users'? I have tried many things and none worked.

Comment: Pretty much anything else above `Users`... You have the entire C: drive at your disposal. It really depends on where you want to put it. If it's something related to your particular app, `%programdata%` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference the C:\Users\Public directory programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649810/how-to-reference-the-c-users-public-directory-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Either use a different directory like Broots recommended or you can get the current user's folder with:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

Which will return C:\Users\Username

Comment: I'm quite new to C#, and would I put that above my text, or at `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: @Marcin That just returns a string. You use it in place of the hard coded C:\Users\X path you have now

Comment: So where do I put it, I really don't know.

Comment: In your code, just replace `@"C:\Users\ME\XXX\XXX\XXX\options.txt"` by `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), @"XXX\XXX\XXX\options.txt")`