# How do I determine the Windows 'Download folder' path?

Tags: c#, windows

On my machine, it's here:

```
string downloadsPath = Path.Combine(
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),
   "Downloads");
```

But on a colleagues machine, this folder doesnt exist, and his Downloads folder is in his 'My Documents' folder. <strike>We are both on Windows 7</strike>*.

***Edit**: in fact, it turns out he was not running the app on his own machine but a Windows Server 2003 machine.

Comment: the "Downloads" folder is localized. for non-english systems, it is not called "Downloads"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically derive Windows Downloads folder "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Windows does not define a [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the Downloads folder and it is not available through the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration.

However, the new Vista [Known Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API does define it with the ID of [`FOLDERID_Downloads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28VS.85%29.aspx). Probably the easiest way to obtain the actual value is to P/invoke [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
public static class KnownFolder
{
    public static readonly Guid Downloads = new Guid("374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B");
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out string pszPath);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string downloads;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(KnownFolder.Downloads, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out downloads);
    Console.WriteLine(downloads);
}
```

Note that the P/invoke given on pinvoke.net is incorrect since it fails to use Unicode character set. Also I have taken advantage of the fact that this API returns memory allocated by the COM allocator. The default marshalling of the P/invoke above is to free the returned memory with `CoTaskMemFree` which is perfect for our needs.

Be careful that this is a Vista and up API and do not attempt to call it on XP/2003 or lower.

Comment: under windows 7 the Downloads folder is a special folder, in that way that I can move it to any specific location that I want. The same way that you can move the My Documents folder etc.

Comment: @Daan There's no [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx) for it so it's not special in that way.

Comment: @Daan But it is defined as a known folder. I was looking in the old CSIDL list.

Comment: seems true, but it is however known as KNOWNFOLDERID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=VS.85).aspx FOLDERID_Downloads

[edit] seems like you already found/answered that part.

Comment: @Daan Yeah, known folders replaced CSIDL which is now deprecated as I understand.

Comment: If you want and are okay with exceptions, you can further take advantage of P/Invoke here with `PreserveSig = false`, making it convert failure `HRESULT`s to appropriate exceptions, and turn the last `out` parameter into the return value.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core/).

Reference: **Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll**

Need the following namespace:

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
```

Simple usage:

```cs
string downloadsPath = KnownFolders.Downloads.Path;
```

Answer (score 0):

The VB.Net function that I use is following

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll")>
Private Function SHGetKnownFolderPath _
    (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal rfid As Guid _
    , ByVal dwFlags As UInt32 _
    , ByVal hToken As IntPtr _
    , ByRef pszPath As IntPtr
    ) As Int32
End Function

Public Function GetDownloadsFolder() As String

    Dim Result As String = ""
    Dim ppszPath As IntPtr
    Dim gGuid As Guid = New Guid("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")

    If SHGetKnownFolderPath(gGuid, 0, 0, ppszPath) = 0 Then
        Result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszPath)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)
    End If
    
   'as recommended by Ray (see comments below) 
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)

    Return Result
End Function
```

In my program, I call it to move some CSV files in another folder.

```
    Dim sDownloadFolder = GetDownloadsFolder()
    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(sDownloadFolder)

    'Move all CSV files that begin with BE in specific folder
    'that has been defined in a CONFIG file (variable: sExtractPath

    For Each fi As FileInfo In di.GetFiles("BE*.csv")
        Dim sFilename = sExtractPath & "\" & fi.Name
        File.Move(fi.FullName, sFilename)
    Next
```

Comment: Microsoft states to free the memory pointed to by ppszPath also in case of the function returning failure. You may want to P/Invoke to a `String` parameter directly and decorate the `DllImport` with `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` to handle this automatically. You can also use `PreserveSig = false` to automatically throw an appropriate exception in case of the `HRESULT` indicating failure (and modify the imported call to return `void`).

Comment: Does this mean that `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)` should be called outside the `If` block ?

Comment: Yes, correct! Even if I've never seen the method return anything else than a null pointer / no memory on failure, I wouldn't rely on that, as it is an implementation detail MS may change any time. It is safe to call `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` on a null pointer anyway, so you can call it without thinking about it too much. Alternatively, you can P/Invoke to a `String` directly as mentioned to let the marshaller do this work, given you specify the `CharSet.Unicode` (and `ExactSpelling = True` to prevent lookup of a non-existent `W` method).

Comment: I've now posted further simplifications of the import [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71954266/777985), if you're interested. I think this is also supported in VB.NET.