# How can I copy my program into a different place on my computer?

Tags: c#, download, copy

How can I copy my program from its source now to a different folder (using C# code)?

P.S: what the C# source of my download folder?

I have no idea how to that :/

Thanks for helpers :-)

Comment: Google is always a great first step.

Comment: @eddie_cat i searched but i found nothing

Comment: I don't believe you. What did you search for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667012/getting-downloads-folder-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying programs is no different than copying any other file. You may use your Operational System's tools to view and move files. You can do it with a graphic interface, example: Finder on Mac OSX, or Windows Explorer on Windows. Or, if you'd rather use command line tools use `cp` on Unix like systems or `copy` on Windows.

If you want to edit files from within your C# program you must the standard library to access the file system (files and folders). The documentation from Microsoft may help you:

[How to: Get Information About Files, Folders, and Drives (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx)

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Minimal example extracted from link above:

```
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
    string targetPath =  @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";

    // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths. 
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    // To copy a file to another location and  
    // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Comment: I want it to be done by my program, i dont want to do it on my own. i asked for the code who do that.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question programmatically.

Comment: I misunderstood you question. Although I'm not fluent on C#, I'm updating my answer to Microsoft's documentations exaplaining how to do it.