# How to reference the current Windows user's video folder path in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, environment-variables, openfiledialog

I am looking for a way to reference the current user's "MyVideos" folder in VB.NET.

I goal is to use this reference to set the `InitialDirectory` propery of my `OpenFileDialog` object. omething lie this:

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
```

under `SpecialDirectories`, I cannot find a property for MyVideos.  The only properties I have under `SpecialDirectories` are:

```
.Desktop
.MyDocuments
.MyMusic
.MyPictures
.Programfiles
.Programs
.Temp
```

Am I missing something?  Is there another way to access this information?

I am able to get the user's root folder, and combine it with "Videos", like this:

```
Dim vidPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Videos")
```

However, that assumes the user has not changed the location of their `My Videos` folder in it's location properties.

[image: My Videos Folder - Location Properties]

I would like to come up with a method to reference this location, in case the user has changed this location setting.

Comment: [This question could help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667012/getting-downloads-folder-in-c/10667108#10667108)

Comment: @Steve & @Plutonix Granted, the answer is helpful, in that it shows me that I can use `dim vidPath as string = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "My Videos")`, however; that assumes the user has not changed the properties of their `My Videos` folder to point to a location other than Windows' default.

Comment: And you are forgetting also the localization problem. In my country is _Video_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing folders in the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration are available via an API call.  There are several C# answers for this, mostly partials (get a specific folder).  VB version for all (?) the missing ones:

```
Public Partial Class NativeMethods

    <DllImport("shell32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SHGetKnownFolderPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> 
                                            rfid As Guid,
                                            dwFlags As UInt32,
                                            hToken As IntPtr,
                                            ByRef pszPath As IntPtr) As Int32
    End Function

   ' in order, below are:
    Public Enum ShellSpecialFolders
        Contacts
        Downloads
        Links
        Music
        Pictures
        SavedGames
        SavedSearches
        Videos
    End Enum

    Private Shared ShellFolderGuids As Guid() = {
                        Guid.Parse("{56784854-C6CB-462B-8169-88E350ACB882}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{4C5C32FF-BB9D-43B0-B5B4-2D72E54EAAA4}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{7D1D3A04-DEBB-4115-95CF-2F29DA2920DA}"),
                        Guid.Parse("{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}")
                                         }

    Friend Shared Function GetSpecialFolder(folder As ShellSpecialFolders) As String
        Dim ret As Int32
        Dim fPath As IntPtr
        ' == "Dont Vertify" flag:
        Dim SHFlag As UInt32 = &H4000

        ret = SHGetKnownFolderPath(ShellFolderGuids(folder), SHFlag,
                                   New IntPtr(0), fPath)

        If ret = 0 Then
            Return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(fPath)
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function

    ' Optional single purpose version
    Friend Shared Function GetSpecialVideoFolder() As String
        Return GetSpecialFolder(ShellSpecialFolders.Videos)
    End Function
'...
End Class
```

Example usage:

```
spath = NativeMethods.GetSpecialFolder(NativeMethods.ShellSpecialFolders.Videos)
Console.WriteLine("Videos are in: {0}", spath)
```

Or if you want to write wrappers for them:

```
spath = NativeMethods.GetSpecialVideoFolder()
```

If you want to get the default folders (rather than `C:\Users\USER NAME\...` you'd get `C:\Users\Default\...`) change the `IntPtr` param to -1:

```
ret = SHGetKnownFolderPath(ShellFolderGuids(folder), SHFlag,
                               New IntPtr(-1), fPath)
```

Results:

[image][image]

Note: The folder returned apparently need not exist.  Especially using the Default version, several folders returned do not actually exist on my system.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!