# How to go to a folder without specify the path

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a button that will open one directory in your computer (for example: `C:\Users\NameOfUser\Downloads`) when you click it. But if I do this on another computer or from another user account with a different name the button doesn’t work. I just used `Process.Start()` for the button.

Is there a different way to do this that will work from any user account?

Comment: Take a look at these two questions and see if that helps you out. They are C# examples but it's still .NET so you should be fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667012/getting-downloads-folder-in-c#21953690 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads

Comment: Should be "NameOfUser" rather than "NameOfPC". It sounds like you named the user account on the machine the same as the computer, but you should understand this folder path is for a user, and not a computer.

Comment: A different user has a different downloads path (and let's not consider the localization question) You need to build the path looking at the Environment.UserName

Comment: @Steve It's worse than that. Windows lets you put the downloads folder anywhere you want. Lots of users like to move this to a D: drive, for example. So the path might not be related to the username at all. To really know the right answer, you need to check the registry (which is itself tricky, because how Windows uses the registry for this has changed over the years) or call a method that checks the registry in the right way for you.

Comment: Can you do an example of Enviroment.GetFolderPath?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I know well the problem. Just look at the deleted answer in that question you have linked below.

Comment: @Steve Gotta love Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get most folder paths like this just by calling `Environment.GetFolderPath()` with the right `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum value. Unfortunately, the `Downloads` special folder in .Net isn't quite "special" enough and (imo) is unreasonably complicated to get. If you actually need to know the path, the **correct** way is to follow the accepted answer here:

> [Getting Downloads Folder in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667012/)

Even worse, it's written for C# and uses code that's not very easy to translate.

The good news is there's also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syroot.Windows.IO.KnownFolders) I'd expect you can use from VB. The even better news is you don't really care about the exact path in this case. You just want to open an Explorer window via `Process.Start()`. That means you can use this shortcut (also available via the other question):

```
Process.Start("shell:Downloads")
```

Comment: Can i use this method to go to folder that is situated in AppData\Roaming?