# When hardcoding a filepath, how do I account for different user profiles?

Tags: vb.net

When hardcoding a filepath, how do I account for different user profiles? For example, below I am using Directory.CreateDirectory to create a series of folders/sub-folders the user will proceed to move files to:

```
    Private Sub btnCreateFolders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateFolders.Click
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\\TEST\\SUB TEST")
    End Sub
```

However, "USERNAME" will be a variable according to the user utilizing the tool.

Comment: See the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) enumerator. The `Downloads` *special* folder is not among these, though. If you need specifically that Directory path, you *could* read the path provided by `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` and go from there, but you probably need [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21953690/7444103). Or read it from the Registry (see other answers there).

Comment: I'm guessing he wants a new folder in `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`; `Downloads` is a pretty peculiar place to put folders “the user will proceed to move files to”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to understand is users can **and do** redirect their downloads folder to weird locations. It's not a good idea at all to assume `C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads` is correct. On my own system, for instance, I have a smallish SSD and a much larger traditional HDD. I prefer my downloads to end up on the HDD, well away from the rest of my profile.

Most of these folders can be had easily using [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) method. For example, the documents folder is here:

```
Dim documents As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Unfortunately, there's no [`SpecialFolder` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) value for the `Downloads` folder. We have to work a little harder. I prefer this [code-project solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/393318/Accessing-the-User-Downloads-Folder-in-VB-NET):

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SHGetKnownFolderPath _
    (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal rfid As Guid _
    , ByVal dwFlags As UInt32 _
    , ByVal hToken As IntPtr _
    , ByRef pszPath As IntPtr
    ) As Int32
End Function

Public Function GetDownloadsFolder() As String
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim ppszPath As IntPtr
    Dim gGuid As Guid = New Guid("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")

    If SHGetKnownFolderPath(gGuid, 0, 0, ppszPath) = 0 Then
        sResult = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppszPath)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszPath)
    End If
    Return sResult
End Function
```

It's really not *that much* code, and it does things the **right way**.

Paste the above as new methods in your existing class, add an `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` to the top of the file, and you can update the code in the question like this:

```
Private Sub btnCreateFolders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateFolders.Click
    Dim SubTest As String = Path.Combine(GetDownloadsFolder(), "TEST\SUB TEST")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SubTest)
End Sub
```

That said, I also agree with the comment saying Downloads is an unusual place for this. The `documents` path used above is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding it, you can build it dynamically with `GetEnvironmentVariable()`. You should concatenate the `HOMEDRIVE` value and the `HOMEPATH`, and then add subfolders after that.

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE") + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH")`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all that answered and commented - I quickly abandoned the idea of using the Downloads folder underestimating the increased difficulty around it. For now I am just identifying the user's desktop, but between everything shared I arrived at (Folders 1, etc just as temp placeholders for now):

```
        Dim dir As String
        dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        dir = Path.Combine(dir, "Folder 1\\Folder 2\\Folder 3\\Folder 4")
        If Not Directory.Exists(dir) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir)
        End If
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You don't need to escape the backslashes - that's a C# thing. That is, use \, not \\.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(dir, "Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3", "Folder 4")`. The entire purpose of `Path.Combine` is to remove escaping or dependencies on path separators.