# Where and how save temporary files in WPF C# app

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a wpf c # application, at user request I download image files from DB (not designed by me). Where should I save these files so that I can open them later in the program?

Comment: Saving files from a .NET application can be done anywhere you want. What you're asking has nothing to do with WPF or any other type of project you've created. You can save it in a C:\Temp folder or save it into the project bin\Debug folder. It depends on your preference.

Comment: I think you want to remove the word "temporary" from your question unless you want files to be automatically deleted after a system reboot or something like that.  What makes these files temporary in your mind?  You can find the _Downloads_ folder [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21953690/1563833).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just call `Path.GetTempPath`.  This will give you a writable folder that is your temp folder.  If you are looking for something specific like a windows Special folder then something like

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`

(or some other [`SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0) value will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a temp file like this:

```
string FileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
FileStream File_Stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Append, 
FileAccess.Write);
//Do what you like with this file
```