# Getting a directory root with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

In order to develop a desktop application for Windows, which will need to know several user's directories of each user, I want to save for example the user's documents directory.

I have found out that already exists some macro (for example CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS) to know its directory's folder, but when I print this information I just get an integer and don't know how to get a string.

Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610787/how-to-get-the-path-to-csidl-common-documents-in-net-3-5):

Comment: What version of Windows are you targeting?

Comment: Well the targets are W7 and W8

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`SHGetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS, NULL, 0, path)))
    {
        std::cout << path;
    }
}
```

Substitute `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` with any [`CSIDL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) you need, such as `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS`.  To get another user's Documents folder, your app will have to impersonate that user, or otherwise obtain an access token for that user, before it can then query any `CSIDL` values that are specific to that user.

Comment: SHGetFolderPath is deprecated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Alan: But still works fine. Microsoft is not in the habit of removing deprecated APIs.

Comment: That seems like a nasty bug in the making.

Comment: @Alan Considering that [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430.aspx) is still available, I'd say that `SHGetFolderPath` is good for another 20 years to come.

Comment: Hi Alan and thanks for your reply. As I get an argument of type Char * is incompatible with parameter of type LPWSTR error, I use wchar_t instead of char. But after this I get in the console "0043F464"

Comment: Let me guess, you are using Visual Studio. If so, you can change your character set.

_Visual Studio_ -> _Project_ -> _Properties_... -> _General_

Change _Character Set_ to Use _Multi-Byte Character Set_.

Answer (score -1):

Using WinAPI, `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` is:

1. Deprecated
2. Not the right folder (it's common documents rather than the specific user document folder).

MSFT recommends using the KNOWNFOLDERID in lieu of `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` but it isn't supported prior to Windows Vista.

If you're building a Windows Application, consider using C++/CLI and .NET libraries, which makes "windowsy" things like accessing user folders, very straight forward.

```
using namespace System;
int main()
{
   Console::WriteLine();
   Console::WriteLine( "GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment::GetFolderPath( Environment::SpecialFolder::MyDocuments) );
}
```

[MSDN Documentation on Environment::SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the question is mainly about getting a string from the CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS constant and its friends, which your answer does not address.

Comment: The question is tagged with the winapi tag. The questioner also did not ask for an alternative.

Comment: I answered the question "Geting a root directory with C++"

Comment: You should also read the question, not only the title. CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS!

Comment: If you read the question, you'd realize that `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` isn't actually what the OP wants. The OP wants to save to users document directory. `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` is the wrong folder.

Comment: I voted your answer up, if only because I couldn't believe people would vote down such a helpful answer. Who cares that it somehow didn't answer the precise question asked? When I search questions on StackOverflow, I usually am not asking the exact question someone else asked, and thus I WANT helpful answers such as yours. I want as much helpful information as possible related to the question, and your answer did precisely that. So, thank you!