# Default "Saved Games" Folder

Tags: c#, windows-7

If I press the start button and search "shell:SavedGames" it brings me right to a folder that seems to exist to contain game saves.  There are many other folders that seem to be a default location for some kinds of data that can be found with the shell: command.  Is there a standard way to access these folders programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the [Special Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)?

```
Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
```

Thanks to Cody's comment for this other link:

[Downloads folder: not special enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/downloads-folder-not-special-enough/3795159#3795159) and also [PInvoke SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetKnownFolderPath.html) which has a list of Guids as well

You'd want to use PInvoke with the GUIDs from

[MSDN - KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
FOLDERID_SavedGames

GUID{4C5C32FF-BB9D-43b0-B5B4-2D72E54EAAA4}
Display Name: Saved Games
Folder Type: PERUSER
Default Path: %USERPROFILE%\Saved Games
CSIDL Equivalent: None, new in Windows Vista
Legacy Display Name: Not applicable
Legacy Default PathNot applicable
```

There is also a (semi old now) Library from Microsoft called [Vista Bridge](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge)

Comment: I found that page but it doesn't have "Saved Games" along with many other folders.  Here's one list I found: http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/pc/shell-folders-the-best-kept-windows-time-saving-secret-464668 I've been doing more research and it looks like the solution may be closer to "SHGetKnownFolderPath": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, "Saved Games" only exists in Vista and newer which is why its probably not in the list I gave you, since it wouldn't return anything for XP machines. This is why Developers probably make so many different Saved Games locations :(

Comment: @Joe: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/downloads-folder-not-special-enough/3795159#3795159) for instructions on how to get at the new special folders that are not provided by the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration.

Comment: @CodyGray that looks like a good work around, though you should probably have it check that it gets a valid path (`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)`) and if not then return the legacy path as well. The `if (hr == 0)` probably covers that but might not always... better safe than sorry when dealing with IO imho.