# How do I move/download a file do a directory without knowing users name?

Tags: vb.net, download

So I am making a downloader/installation program and I want it to download to a folder in the roaming folder but I need to know the users name (current logged in users) to be able to move a file there how would I accomplish this?

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` The Downloads folder is not one of the enumerated ones.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3795023/1070452

Comment: Your question should have been "how to determine the home folder using the .Net framework?" What you do with it does not really matter after that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you the Desktop folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment. SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Similarly, you can get the other special folders using the other enum values of Environment. SpecialFolder