# Get default download location set by the user for his PC

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In my PC, I've changed my default downloads folder from "C:\Users\MyProfile\Downloads" to "D:\Downloads".

Now, in my UWP app, I am able to save the files that user downloads from my app in the "D:\Downloads" using the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage) API [DownloadsFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) class. But I need to display the path, where the files are getting downloaded, to the user.

I'm not able to fetch the location which the user has set as his default download location in the case as I have said above (from c: drive to d: drive).

Is there any way to check if the user has set a different location for his downloads and if so get the folder path?

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads")
```

The above code always gives "C:\Users\MyProfile\Downloads". But I've changed my download location to D: drive.

Comment: no there isnt a way to check that so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically derive windows downloads folder "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads)

Comment: Can you not just tell them "it's in your downloads folder"? If they've moved it, they should know where they've moved it to. If they haven't, they should still be able to find it easily (after all, it's a shortcut in the left pane of explorer windows)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In UWP, a folder will be created inside the downloads folder with my app name, and files will be stored inside this app folder. So it will be better if I display the path. If not there is a chance that the user might be searching for the files directly in the downloads folder instead of searching for a folder with my app's name inside his downloads folder.

Comment: Cannot try it now, but my first thought is create a temp file in the Downloads folder and then check the [Path property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.path#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_Path) of the file.

Comment: @kennyzx ya I thought of that approach, but since it would unnecessarily create a temp file, I wanted to check if there is any direct way to get the downloads folder path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the `DownloadsFolder`'s path that the user set on the device directly. You can only get the download folder's path by the `StorageFile` or `StorageFolder`'s `Path` property where you created them in the `DownloadsFolder`.

You can do a trick to get the `DownloadsFolder`'s path by the steps: Create a file in the `DownloadsFolder` => Get the file's path and save the path => Delete the file.

```
private async Task<string> GetDownloadsFolderPath()
{
    StorageFile newFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("mytestfile");
    if (newFile != null)
    {
        //You maybe need to operate the DownloadFolderPath string to subtract the folder name of your app.
        string DownloadFolderPath = newFile.Path;
        await newFile.DeleteAsync();
        return DownloadFolderPath;
    }
    else
    {
        return "There is an error to get path";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is StorageFile and why do you need that when you already have a ``DownloadsFolder`` class... I can't find any of these objects...