# How can I move a downloaded file to the users temp path?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've looked it up on google, tried any answers for myself and none worked. I want to download 2 files and save them both to the users temp file (C:\Users%UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp). I can easily find the temp file using a string (string tempPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");) I just can't get farther than that at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download directly into the temp folder:

```
using System.Net;

string tempPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/file/file1.txt", @$"{tempPath}\file.txt");    
    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/file/file2.txt", @$"{tempPath}\file2.txt");
}
```

Or move the already downloaded file:

```
using System.IO;

string tempPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");

File.Move(@"C:\User\Downloads\Filename.txt", @$"{tempPath}\file.txt");
File.Move(@"C:\User\Downloads\Filename2.txt", @$"{tempPath}\file2.txt");
```

The `@` before the string is the **string literal** and The `$` is the **string interpolation** you can search for these nice features later.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer:

you can also derive the download-folder path to work on machine which use a different download folder as the default. You can find input on that here: [How to programmatically derive Windows Downloads folder "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/how-to-programmatically-derive-windows-downloads-folder-userprofile-downloads)

So if you chose to implement the second solution (moving files already downloaded) and need to roll this out on other machines than your own, this probably is a good idea.